# Creating Category Attribute in Magento 1.9.2 via setup script

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I would like to create three different category attribute, a custom input text, a wysiwyg text area, and another category image upload.

I started first on custom input text as I think the easiest but it doesn't work. I checked the core_resource to see if the version was registered but it wasn't and the attribute was not present on the category.

This is my code

app/etc/modules/Rnd_Customheader.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Rnd_Customheader>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
    </Rnd_Customheader>
</modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Rnd/Customheader/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Rnd_Customheader>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Rnd_Customheader>
</modules>
<global>
    <resources>
        <Rnd_Customheader_setup>
          <setup>
               <module>Rnd_Customheader</module>
               <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
          </setup>
          <connection>
            <use>default_setup</use>
          </connection>
      </Rnd_Customheader_setup>
    </resources>  
</global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Rnd/Customheader/sql/rnd_customheader_setup

```
<?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $attribute  = array(
        'type'          =>  'text',
        'label'         =>  'Custom Header (If you want different page header)',
        'input'         =>  'text',
        'global'        =>  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'       =>  true,
        'required'      =>  false,
        'user_defined'  =>  true,
        'default'       =>  "",
        'group'         =>  "General Information"
    );
    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_header', $attribute);
    $installer->endSetup();
?>
```

This are my references

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94833/add-custom-attribute-for-category

http://gauss-development.com/blog/tutorials/adding-custom-category-attributes-magento/

Are there missing or steps I missed?

If i'm right, this extension will run once the page refreshes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447763/creating-new-attribute-field-in-catalog-manage-categories-display-settings/33472607#33472607

Comment: @rodge can please mention install script name ?

Comment: This is the name of the install script mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
         <Rnd_Customheader>
             <version>0.1.0</version>
         </Rnd_Customheader>
      </modules>
      <global>
        <resources>
    <customheader_setup>
      <setup>
           <module>Rnd_Customheader</module>
           <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
      </setup>
      <connection>
        <use>default_setup</use>
      </connection>
  </customheader_setup>
</resources>
```

Change *Rnd_Customheader_setup* to *customheader_setup* and rename the dircetory to *app/code/local/Rnd/Customheader/sql/customheader_setup*

Also make sure install script name should be *mysql4-install-0.1.0.php*, here 0.1.0 is your module version.